# Overflow scroll show div moved outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have objects inside of a div that set with overflow hidden. I am trying to get one object outside of the div and make him visible even that he's parent div set to overflow hidden.

Could someone give me a hint for a direction to think in? Not really sure how to pull this off

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: please provide code or upload code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this cannot be done :( - I've had the same issue (with a pop-up on a carousel/slider) and I had to create the pop-ups outside the overflow: hidden div. However, I'll be interested if you can find a solution . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you have an exact offset where the item is displayed, you could use position: absolute;

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        Im 50px below/nexto my wrapping div
    </div>
    <div id="overflowControl">
        text
        text
        text <!-- About from here things wont be visible -->
        text
            text
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#div1{
     height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: pink;
}
#overflowControl{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#div2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    background: limegreen;
    z-index: 100;
}
```